# Jenkins Pipeline Plugin - withMaven Step leads to com.google.inject.CreationException

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, maven-plugin, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins 2.19.1 (Latest LTS Release) with all Plugins up to date

I use a build pipeline to execute several maven tasks. My pipeline code looks like this example:

```
stage("checkout git") {
   // .....
}

stage("build app") {
  node {
    withMaven(maven:'Maven_3_3_9', mavenLocalRepo: '.repository',mavenSettingsConfig:'my-config') {
      sh 'mvn clean install'
  }
}

stage("deploy app") {
   node {
     withMaven(maven:'Maven_3_3_9', mavenLocalRepo: '.repository',mavenSettingsConfig:'my-config') {
       sh 'mvn deploy'
   }
}
```

If i use the "Safe Restart Plugin" or the "Prepare for Restart Option" and restart the Jenkins the pipeline will crash when the next maven task in the pipeline is executed and throws the following error:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withMaven
[Pipeline] // withMaven
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) A just-in-time binding to org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.maven.WithMavenStep was already configured on a parent injector.
  at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ContextParameterModule.configure(ContextParameterModule.java:37)

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:448)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createChildInjector(InjectorImpl.java:230)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createChildInjector(InjectorImpl.java:237)
    at jenkins.ProxyInjector.createChildInjector(ProxyInjector.java:110)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractStepImpl.prepareInjector(AbstractStepImpl.java:43)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractStepImpl.start(AbstractStepImpl.java:36)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:182)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:126)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:16)
    at maven.call(/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jndiagent-INTEGRATION/builds/27/libs/com.timocom.jenkins.pipeline/vars/maven.groovy:22)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:44)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:48)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:324)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:78)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:236)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:224)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

All the documentations say that pipeline jobs are resilient to Jenkins restarts but it seems that there is a problem with the maven enviroment created by the "withMavenStep". Other jobs using the "withMaven" step will also fail untill I restart the Jenkins again. Maybe the environment is not cleaned up properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not solve the problem yet, but i found a workaround. Instead of using the `withMaven` step I use the `tool` step to init a maven environment. This way is restart resilent and works for me. But I did not figure out what causes the initial problems. I also created an issue on the jenkins issue tracker, but there is no response so far:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39134

My workaround:

```
// use the id of the globally configured maven instance
def mvnTool = tool 'Maven_3_3_9'

// execute maven
sh "${mvnTool}/bin/mvn clean install"
```

The maven config location is `$JENKINS_HOME/.m2`

Comment: Have you tried installing the maven pipeline plugin ?